# Interest Accrual and insert monthly records since start date

Tags: sql-server, query, date, sum, computed-column

I need to calculate the (1) "To" date after the initial contribution amount to accrue for accounting interest. The "TO" is calculated as

- End of month date if no other are events in Account ID 1 (contr), 2 (dist), or 3 (returns).
- If there is a subsequent event, "To" date is equal to 1 date minus the date of event in Account ID 1,2, or 3. For example, an event occurs in July 31, 2018. The "To" date for the initial contribution amount dated on July 3 is equal to July 30 2018. The "To" date for second event from July 31, 2018 July 31, 2018.

(2) I need to generate Start and Month end of dates following the initial contribution date.  After the first 2 events above, the 3rd row will be for August 1 (From) to August 31 (To) to accrue for interest in above accounts.

(3) The Monthly records (From) to (To)  will be generated until current date and running balance from totals for Account ID (1,2,3).

I am limited to views in SQL and recursion limit of 100.  I created a vw_calendar based on fiscal calendar table I can reference in the query.

[image]